# How to parse each row JSON to columns of Spark 2 DataFrame?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my Spark (2.2) DataFrame each row is JSON:

```
df.head()
//output
//[{"key":"111","event_name":"page-visited","timestamp":1517814315}]

df.show()
//output
//+--------------+
//|         value|
//+--------------+
//|{"key":"111...|
//|{"key":"222...|
```

I want to pass each JSON row to columns in order to get this `result`:

```
key   event_name     timestamp
111   page-visited   1517814315
...
```

I tried this approach, but it does not give me an expected result:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Seq(
     StructField("key", StringType, true), StructField("event_name", StringType, true), StructField("timestamp", IntegerType, true)
))

val result = df.withColumn("value", from_json($"value", schema))
```

and:

```
result.printSchema()
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- event_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
```

while it should be:

```
result.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select($"value.*")` in the end to select the elements of `struct` column into separate columns as

```
val result = df.withColumn("value", from_json($"value", schema)).select($"value.*")
```